# Theorem 2.1.4 of the paper Deferred Statistical Convergence of Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I am reading [this paper](http://pdf.medrang.co.kr/kmj/56/kmj056-02-05.pdf) stuck at **Theorem 2.1.4**

The inequation $${1\over{q(n)-p(n)}}\sum_{k=p(n)+1}^{q(n)}|x_k-l|\le M {1\over{q(n)-p(n)}}|\{k:p(n)\lt k\le q(n) , |x_k-l|\ge \epsilon\}|\\+\epsilon{{1\over{q(n)-p(n)}}|\{k:p(n)\lt k\le q(n) , |x_k-l|\lt \epsilon\}}|$$
is established. Then it says that from the limit relations we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{1\over {q(n)-p(n)}}\sum_{k=p(n)+1}^{q(n)}|x_k-l|=0$$

I know the first summand of RHS tends to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ by definition of $DS[p,q]$ convergence but what ensures that the second summand also tends to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty \ ?$

Please help somebody.

Comment: did my best cleaning up the syntax errors, please double check everything is as you intend it to be

Comment: From your heading it sounds like you are reading it out loud.

Comment: @mathreadler : thank you very much for that. Actually I'm having some connection problem maybe. I cannot see anything after typing.:(

Comment: @IanMiller : This is the third question I have posted from this particular PAPER  but none has been answered. I figured out the first one myself though but this and another one are giving me hard time. I know this is newly published but there must be some people who have read it. I am waiting for answers. :/

Answer (score 1):

You immediately have $$\varepsilon{{1\over{q(n)-p(n)}}|\{k:p(n)\lt k\le q(n) , |x_k-l|\lt \varepsilon\}}| \le \varepsilon$$ simply because the set has at most $q(n)-p(n)$ elements.

So for any fixed $\varepsilon>0$ you get that
$$0\le {1\over {q(n)-p(n)}}\sum_{k=p(n)+1}^{q(n)}|x_k-l| \le \varepsilon$$
is true for each large enough $n$. This is basically the definition of
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over {q(n)-p(n)}}\sum_{k=p(n)+1}^{q(n)}|x_k-l|=0.$$